# jquery как достучаться до объекта - получить его значение

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Я получаю объект с youtube и закидываю данные в таблицу на сайте. есть код:

```
productsModule.controller("addNewVideo", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
$scope.addNewVideo = function () {

/*======  GET DATA FROM YOUTUBE API =========*/

$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=' + $scope.videourl + "&key=AIzaSyDnyf5NK_oWcdWjFw6VrILvGg2STG292eE&part=snippet&callback=?", function (data) {

    if (typeof (data.items[0]) != "undefined") {
        var title = "";
        title = JSON.stringify(data.items[0].snippet.title);
        title = title.substring(1, title.length - 1);
        title = title.split("-");
        console.log(data.items[0]);

        //====== CREATE OBJECT OF NEW SONG
        var newSong = {
                "artist": title[0],
                "song": title[1],
                "songID": $scope.videourl
            }
            //  $scope.videourl = "test11" ;
        var tr = '<tr><td class=" songID hide" contenteditable="false">'     + $scope.videourl + '</td><td id="artistName" class="x2" name="x1" contenteditable="true">' + title[0] + '</td>  <td id="songName" contenteditable="true">' + title[1] + '</td><td> <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td><td> <span class="table-play glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span></td><td>  <span class="table-save glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></td></tr>';
        $("#songTable").append(tr);
```

я получаю строку на своем сайте с данными.(строк может быть сколько угодно) следующий акт марлезонского балета - при нажатии на кнопку "сохранить", я должен забрать данные с своей HTML страницы и переправить их в базу данных. забрать нужно ID, имя артиста и название песни. У меня не получается достучаться до данных.

```
// add song to table songs  

$('.table-save').click(function () { // удалить запись о песне
    //  var x1 = $(this).find("x1").value;
    var x1 = $(this).parent().find(".x2").val;

    alert(x1);
```

---

пришел к тому что получаю много данных... но что дальше???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте так `var x1 = $(this).parent().parent().find(".x2").val;`

Comment: @ L.Vadim не срабатываетю  выдает много данных, но по сути ничего нужного.

Comment: вы можете поставить в вопрос полный код с html

Comment: Ваши `много данных` - это функция, которую надо было вызвать.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо -  разобрался. 
Если кому будет нужно -  вот действующий код:

```
  $('.table-save').click(function () {
                var newSongObj = {};

                $(this).parent().parent().find(".x2").each(function () {
                    var objAttr = $(this).attr("id");
                    newSongObj[objAttr] = $(this).html();
                })
                console.log(newSongObj);
                $http.post('/addSongToDB', newSongObj).then(function (response) {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                    var xxx = JSON.stringify(response.data);


                });
```